# Visual Studios Team System 2008 Code Coverage Window Closes

Tags: visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, code-coverage

Trying to run the code coverage tool in Visual Studios for a set of unit tests.  Adam from [Think First, Code Later](http://thinkfirstcodelater.com/blog/?p=437) has had the same problem:

> I wanted to get the code coverage
>   metrics for the project. Naturally, I
>   fire up the solution in Visual Studio
>   2008, go to the Test menu, click Edit
>   Test Run Configurations, and click
>   Local Test Run. I then click Code
>   Coverage to turn on code coverage for
>   a given assembly and *POOF* the Local
>   Test Run Configraution window just
>   disappears.

He recommends installing this [hotfix](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/KB962866) to fix the problem, however a) when I run that hotfix I get the message “None of the products that are addressed by this software update are installed on this computer. Click Cancel to exit setup.” and b) there is no Silverlight in our solution.

Any other ideas for a fix?

Comment: Link: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/361591/cant-open-code-coverage-page-with-the-test-run-config-and-dialog-colses-itself-if-the-solution-includes-biztalk-projects